# DNS troubleshooting

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I'm the sysadmin at my company out of necessity. I'm not actually that knowledgeable. It's probably helpful to know that when I'm asking my question.

We have a DNS server here that I set up a few months ago. Today our internet stopped working (somebody unplugged the firewall) and after we plugged the firewall back in I restarted the DNS server. When the DNS server booted back up, the internet still didn't work, so I ran `sudo named` on the DNS server and the internet started working for everyone again.

However, domains on our intranet don't work anymore. I have several intranet sites on the `.office` domain that have never had problems and now they don't work anymore. The machines the DNS server pointed to now have different IP addresses, but I updated those IP addresses, so it seems like it should work.

I'm using Ubuntu with BIND. Given my limited experience with DNS, I don't know what to try. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For restart:

```
# service bind restart
```

For debug, run named in foreground and send log to console:

```
# /usr/sbin/named -u bind -g -d 1
```

See log:

```
less /var/log/syslog
```

Check named process:

```
ps aux | grep name
```

Check port listen:

```
lsof -i udp:53
```

Comment: These didn't lead me to the answer but they're all helpful suggestions so I'm selecting this as the "correct" answer. I ended up using `named-checkconf` and `named-checkzone` to see if my config files were sound and it turns out they were not. Knowing this allowed me to fix my config files and now my DNS server is working again.

Comment: @Jason, especially at this early stage it's important to run those checks whenever you modify the zone files or configuration. Saves getting nasty surprises later. Your problem also suggests you may not have reloaded the configs last time they were changed, otherwise you should have noticed this problem earlier.